# Display charts inside div elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my controller create the chart:

```
var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 600)
    .AddTitle("Employee's Efficiency")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Employee",
        xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
        yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .Write();
myChart.Save("~/Content/chart" + pid, "jpeg");
return base.File("~/Content/chart" + pid, "jpeg");
```

and my razor view display it:

```
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Contas e Despesas <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></h1>
    <p class="lead">Onde gastei o meu dinheiro?    Controle melhor as suas despesas com o Contas e Despesas. </p>
</div>
<div>
   <img src="@Url.Action("EfficiencyChart", "Home", new { pid = @Model.Id })" />
</div>
```

My problem is that the images override the whole page.. i can't display my jumbotron or anything else except the chart image :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a chart inside view itself as shown :-

```
@{
var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 600)
        .AddTitle("Employee's Efficiency")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
        myChart.Save("~/Content/chart" + @Model.Id, "jpeg");
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Contas e Despesas <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></h1>
    <p class="lead">Onde gastei o meu dinheiro?    Controle melhor as suas despesas com o Contas e Despesas. </p>
</div>
<div>
   <img src="@myChart" />
</div>
```

Don't forget to add related namespaces inside view as well.

**OR**

Instead of

```
<img src="@Url.Action("EfficiencyChart", "Home", new { pid = @Model.Id })" />
```

Try

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("EfficiencyChart", "Home", new { pid = @Model.Id }); }
```

Controller(Home) :-

```
public ActionResult EfficiencyChart(int pid)
{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 600)
        .AddTitle("Employee's Efficiency")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
        myChart.Save("~/Content/chart" + pid, "jpeg");
    return File("~/Content/chart" + pid, "image/jpeg");// <----change here
}
```

**OR**

Controller(Home) :-

```
public ActionResult EfficiencyChart(int pid)
{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 600)
        .AddTitle("Employee's Efficiency")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .GetBytes("jpeg");

    return File(myChart , "image/jpeg"); // <----change here
}
```

View :-

```
<img src="@Url.Action("EfficiencyChart", "Home", new { pid = @Model.Id })" />
```

Comment: ok, but i need to do this logic inside my controller to use values from my DB.. how can i do that inside controllers?

Comment: @user2002274..and try changing height and width of chart with somewhat smaller values..